# An Issue with Cogs (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Alright so I had some code that was working perfectly without cogs. I created two uses for my bot then decided it was time to start using cogs so that is what I did. The first of my first of my uses was a reaction role maker. So I copied the code and put it in a cog and changed all of the things that I knew that I had to change (`client.command` -> `commands.command` for example.) When I try to run the code the reaction role doesn't work and I get no errors.

This is my code in `main.py`

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands
import os
import asyncio

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=">",intents=intents)

asta_guild_id = 1030203387423236136

# Cogs Setup
async def load():
    for filename in os.listdir("./Cogs"):
      if filename.endswith(".py"):
        await bot.load_extension(f"Cogs.{filename[:-3]}")

@bot.event
async def on_connect():
    print("Bot has connected!")
    
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is Ready!")

async def main():
  await load()
  await bot.start("MY_TOKEN", reconnect=True)

asyncio.run(main())
```

And this is my code in `Cogs/ReactionRoles.py`

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands

asta_guild_id = 1030203387423236136

class ReactionRoles(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @app_commands.command()
    async def rr(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author.top_role.permissions.administrator == True:             
            channel_id = 1039476995324649572   
            await ctx.reply(f"I will DM you once the reaction roles have been created.")
            #Title
            embed=discord.Embed(title="『』Reaction Roles!",description=f"React with the corresponding emoji to customise your roles!")
            title_msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            #Ping Roles
            embed1=discord.Embed(title="『』Ping Roles:",description=f"React with  to get pinged for Giveaways\nReact with ⌨️ to get pinged for Chat Revival\nReact with ️ to get pinged for Announcements\nReact with  to get pinged for Staff Notices")
            ping_roles = await ctx.send(embed=embed1)
            await ping_roles.add_reaction("")
            await ping_roles.add_reaction("⌨️")
            await ping_roles.add_reaction("️")
            await ping_roles.add_reaction("")
            embed2=discord.Embed(title="『』Color Roles:",description=f"React with  for red colour\nReact with  for green colour\nReact with  for blue colour\nReact with <:pink_square:1041820443692249109> for blue colour")
            col_roles = await ctx.send(embed=embed2)
            await col_roles.add_reaction("")
            await col_roles.add_reaction("")
            await col_roles.add_reaction("")
            await col_roles.add_reaction("<:pink_square:1041820443692249109>")    
            dmchannel = await ctx.author.create_dm()
            dmembed=discord.Embed(title="",description=f"I have finished setting up the reaction roles in [Reaction Roles]({title_msg.jump_url})")
            await dmchannel.send(embed=dmembed)
        else:
            channel_id = 1039476995324649572
            Channel = commands.get_channel(channel_id)
            await ctx.reply("Only admins can complete this command.")

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, ctx, payload):
        Channel = commands.get_channel(1039476995324649572)
        if payload.channel_id != 1039476995324649572:
            return
        await ctx.send("hi")
        guild = await self.commands.Bot.fetch_guild(payload.guild_id)
        user = await guild.fetch_member(payload.user_id)
        #Ping Roles   
        if payload.emoji.name == "":
            Role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Giveaway")
            await user.add_roles(Role)
            print("321")
        if payload.emoji.name == "⌨️":
            Role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Chat revival")
            await user.add_roles(Role)
        if payload.emoji.name == "️":
            Role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Announcement")
            await user.add_roles(Role)
        if payload.emoji.name == "":
            Role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Staff Notices")
            await user.add_roles(Role)
        #Colour Roles
        if payload.emoji.name == "":
            Role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Red")
        await user.add_roles(Role)
        if payload.emoji.name == "":
            Role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Green")
        await user.add_roles(Role)
        if payload.emoji.name == "":
            Role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Blue")
        await user.add_roles(Role)
        if payload.emoji.name == "pink_square":
            Role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Pink")
        await user.add_roles(Role)

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):
        Channel = commands.get_channel(1039476995324649572)
        guild = commands.get_guild(asta_guild_id)
        if payload.channel_id != Channel.id:
            return
        message = await Channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
        user = await guild.fetch_member(payload.user_id)
        #Ping Roles   
        if payload.emoji.name == "":
            Role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Giveaway")
        await user.remove_roles(Role)
        if payload.emoji.name == "⌨️":
            Role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Chat revival")
        await user.remove_roles(Role)
        if payload.emoji.name == "️":
            Role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Announcement")
        await user.remove_roles(Role)
        if payload.emoji.name == "":
            Role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Staff Notices")
        await user.remove_roles(Role)
        #Colour Roles
        if payload.emoji.name == "":
            Role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Red")
        await user.remove_roles(Role)
        if payload.emoji.name == "":
            Role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Green")
        await user.remove_roles(Role)
        if payload.emoji.name == "":
            Role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Blue")
        await user.remove_roles(Role)
        if payload.emoji.name == "pink_square":
            Role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Pink")
        await user.remove_roles(Role)

async def setup(bot):
  await bot.add_cog(ReactionRoles(bot))
```

The bot just does nothing whenever I right >rr. It is not replying whatsoever to the commands/listeners in the cogs. Please help I have spent like 2 days trying to fix this and tried to research as much as possible

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```py
@commands.command()
```

to this:

```py
@app_commands.command()
```

the decorator has an other name inside a cog.

Comment: I assume this turns my command into a slash command and now I have to wait for me to test my command. Is there a way to may slash commands load faster?

Comment: I have updated my post with my current code and I am still getting no response (it seems like everything in the cog is ignored.)